# Is there a best practice to make an expandable row in CSS grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So for the site I'm working on I frequently need to have table views, but often the individual rows in the view also need to be expanded to fill in additional info. In the past we've used flex to achieve this and it works, but we're migrating to css grids and I'm trying to figure out if there is a best practice for doing this. What I have works, but I'm not familiar enough yet with grid have a good feeling for the best ways to achieve this.

Right now I'm using col span to achieve this, but wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this type of behavior.

I should make note that the number of rows is variable, I just statically defined them in the plunkr to keep the code simple.

Here's examples of the grid and flex methods I'm using.

https://plnkr.co/edit/T4HOvXG63ho4ONZoykhp

```
.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.expandRow{
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.flex{
  display:flex;
}

.flex1{
  flex:1
}

 <body>

    <h3>Grid</h3>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>header</div>
      <div>header</div>
      <div>header</div>
      <div>row1</div>
      <div>row1</div>
      <div>row1</div>
      <div class="expandRow">
        I'm an expansion of the row 1
      </div>
      <div>row2</div>
      <div>row2</div>
      <div>row2</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Flex</h3>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex1">header</div>
        <div class="flex1">header</div>
        <div class="flex1">header</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class=flex>
          <div class="flex1">row1</div>
          <div class="flex1">row1</div>
          <div class="flex1">row1</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          I'm an expansion of the row 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=flex>
        <div class="flex1">row2</div>
        <div class="flex1">row2</div>
        <div class="flex1">row2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: `grid-column: span 3` is a clean and valid rule. There are several other ways to achieve the same thing in grid, but you'll need to be more precise about your requirements for a more specific solution.

Comment: The normal practice for us is to have a hidden row that expands when a user clicks on something. Basically just way to have a normal table looking view, but then to expand the row itself so that you can see the details. Although I think with my current implementation you run in to the problem that zebra striping doesn't really work anymore.